# Sublime Text 3 syntax - replacing on screen character in source with different visual

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I get the feeling that this isn't going to be possible in Sublime Text 3 but I am curious if such real-time modification of the source view is available.

In my programming language we use `^ (carat)` as the assignment operator so that:

```
"ABC"^Var1
```

String ABC is assigned to variable Var1.

In our actual environment the `^ carat[ascii 94]` is replaced with `→ arrow-right [ascii 8594]` so that the above statement would instead look like:

```
"ABC"→Var1
```

Simply put I want to replace all occurrences of ^ with → in my source view only, with the original ^ being the actual saved and compiled value (not the display only: → character). This is purely for display during coding only.

INFO: Using Sublime Text 3 Build 3103 with Package Manager in Win7 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea:
Take the font you are using in your editor and replace the carat `^` with the arrow `→`. This would make it work in any Editor and the character which is saved/compiled is always the carat.

[FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io) should do that job. If it's not possible to change your `.ttf` or `.otf` font use an open source font like [Adobe Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro) and change it there.

By the way, Sublime Text can use [different preferences per file type](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file-type-preferences). This way you can make use of your special font only for your special language and leave it the normal font for any other language.

Comment: I really like the idea of font editing and Font Forge is a very cool program, I ended up moving right arrow to the carat position and saving. Unfortuntely when my font was rendered by FontForge it totally destroyed it, creating a barely legible output (but the arrow worked!)



I guess I need to spend more time learning how to properly generate a font from Font Forge that creates smooth results based on the smooth paths instead of a jagged monstrosity.

Comment: Here's what FontForge is doing on generate, do you have experience with this? It's like smoothing/anti aliasing effects or something similar are no longer applied. I will continue to learn. http://i.imgur.com/IcggGW3.png

Comment: @ChrisRiley Sorry but I don't have much experience with FontForge myself, maybe you ask at a font designer forum. Or have a look at the Adobe Source Code Pro they have information on Github on how to build from source which should produce the same result as them. But I don't know how easy it is to change the sources either. But any font professional should be able to help you with that at least. I just had the idea to change it in the font could be easier than hacking a specific editor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did figure it out and will provide the answer here for posterity in case someone googles into this post.

In Windows fonts require hinting to appear smooth at small sizes. Hinting tells Windows what parts of the font are important, so it can prioritize what to render when small.   

http://www.freetype.org/ttfautohint/#download Is popular for hinting,  as well as the autohint utility which is part of the Adobe Font Development Kit for Open Type (used also with your Adobe Source Code Pro) http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html